# Infinite loop when calling login page of a java web application

Tags: java

I am creating a web application using Java and I am having a problem on sessions. Below are the following scenario:

1. Open the login page of the web app on one tab
2. Open the same login page of the same web app on another tab using the same browser.

The problem that I encountered is on the second attempt, there is an infinite loop and I cannot seem to open the login page of the web app. The other scenario for the second option is after opening the login page of the web app, try to close it and open it again. There is still an infinite loop and the login page does not appear normally as expected.

Do you have any idea or have you already encountered the same problem as I did?

Thank you!

Comment: Post your code so we could help you.

Comment: Yes, I have encountered this.  This could be caused by landing on a page which immediately forwards itself to the same page.  Then, you would get the same page loading infinitely.  Add code and output for best results, though.

Comment: Hi, please see http://collabedit.com/kgavd

Answer (score 0):

You must include your login page in to the list of pages which does not require login. You should do that in your web application config.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be that helpful, but I suggest that you use the session to determine if the user is logged in. You can make a SessionHelper class.

> SessionHelper.java

```
public class SessionHelper {

    public SessionHelper() {
    }

    public static Boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return (Boolean) UI.getCurrent().getSession().getAttribute("loggedOn");
    }

    public static void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedOn){
        UI.getCurrent().getSession().setAttribute("loggedOn",loggedOn);
    }

    public static void setLoggedIn(boolean loggedOn){
        UI.getCurrent().getSession().setAttribute("loggedOn",loggedOn);
    }

    public static void logIn(){
        setLoggedIn(true);
    }

    public static void logOut(){
        setLoggedIn(false);
    }
    //add other relevant methods here. 
}
```

the SessionHelper class will be used to determine if the user is logged in. You can use the logIn() upon logging in with correct details and logOut() upon clicking "log out".

Then you can use the value stored in session when trying to visit a page like this:

```
//(just a pseudocode)
if SessionHelper.isLoggedIn(){
    let_the_user_visit_the_page. use_the_details_in_session_helper_
}else{
    ask_the_user_to_log_in
}
```